# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, nullpointerexception, wsdl

im trying to execute the program that should access the webservice using Main method, im getting below error, im working on stand alone class, not on any server,

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.eccBPNoSyncSI(Unknown Source)
    at za.co.interfile.cf.BPDetailsRoe.getBPDetails(BPDetailsRoe.java:71)
    at za.co.interfile.cf.BPDetailsRoe.getBPNumber(BPDetailsRoe.java:38)
    at za.co.interfile.cf.BPDetailsRoe.main(BPDetailsRoe.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:202)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:177)
    ... 19 more

im able to access the webservices using SOAP UI, or when i deploy to glassfish, now im trying to do stand alone program that will execute the webservice, i have searched on similar problems, most of them they talk about when u deploy to certain server, im not deploying to any server for this problem,

Comment: @Jesper please refer me to the original for question like this, as the once im have seen when i search , they more on issue after deploying to servers, and at this point im not deploying to any server

Comment: There's a link above, see the yellow block above your question.